# How to split an array in half until chunks of a certain size are reached?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array with a variable length that is greater than 3 and can be odd or even.

For example: `var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];`

Now I want to split that array into halves.

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and `['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']`

Next I want to split those chunks into halves and to keep doing that until the chunks have a length of 3 or 2.

Finally I want to store those chunks in a new array.

`var newarr = [['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['f','g','h'],['i','j']];`

How would I do this?

Comment: So your end result will be nested? (i.e. if you'll do that 3 times, you'll get nested 3-dimension array?)

Comment: You can use recursion for this.

Comment: `var newArr = arr.slice(0,Number(arr.length/2));`

Comment: @AlmaDo My end result will be nested, like in my example. However, the end result would only be nested twice, no more. So `newarr` would only contain the final chunks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A self-suggesting way to do this is to use a recursive function F: for an input array `arr` if its length is <= 3 then the result is `[arr]`, otherwise it is `F(first_half_of_arr)` concatenated with `F(second_half_of_arr)`.

In code this translates to:

```
function recursiveSplit(arr) { 
    return arr.length <= 3 ? [arr] : 
        recursiveSplit(arr.slice(0, Math.ceil(arr.length / 2)))
        .concat(recursiveSplit(arr.slice(Math.ceil(arr.length / 2))));
}
```

You can exclude the `Math.ceil` calls, but if you do you are going to get the 2-length chunks before the 3-length ones in your result.

Now *in practice* an iterative implementation should be much more performant than a recursive one because it won't need to create and abandon small arrays entirely, so if this is expected to operate on large arrays you should probably stay away from recursion.

Comment: Very elegant! This does exactly what I want it to do. However, it is possible that my arrays will be quite large, as in a few hundred items. So, what would an iterative implementation look like?

Comment: @MaxGruson: A few hundred won't be a problem. Anyway, does it matter in which position exactly any 3-chunks will appear? If so, what's the exact requirement?

Comment: All right, sorry for my noobish definition of large. The correct position was already achieved by splitting the array like this, so that's fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
var arr1 = arr.splice(0, Math.ceil(arr.length / 2));
```

That will split an array in half, so now arr contain second half of original array and arr1 contains first half.

You should be able to just repeat in a while loop:

```
while (arr > 3) {
    //continue splicing
}
```

If you don't think this answer is good enough (It probably makes no sense to anyone other than me, I am so tired right now) please just comment rather than disliking.